# How do I get nodejs to run without a port number on a Apache server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, apache, codeigniter

I have a nodejs api application running inside a codeigniter environment. Im trying to access the nodejs api's without using a port number in the url

currently you can only hit the node api at

```
http://wrl.xx.com:8010/api
```

And I would like to have it accessible through a url like :

```
http://wrl.xx.com/api/
```

I tried to run a reverse proxy with no success

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName wrl.xx.com

ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8010/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8010/
ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you intend to differentiate requests looking for the nodejs app from requests seeking the codigniter app by seeing `/api` as the root path, try:

```
ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8010/api
ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8010/api
```

See [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPass)  and [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPassReverse) for more magic.

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I have no experience with codeigniter, so this may be non relevant, or false.*

Your node.js server listen to port 8010, which is non standard, that is why you need to indicate it in the URL.

You seems to imply codeigniter is already listening to the standard port (80).
The way I see, with no knowledge of codeigniter, to go around the issue would be to either host all the node.js url in codeigniter, and redirect them to port 8010:

```
Client call /node on port 80
CodeIgniter call /node on himself at port 8010
Node get the request and answer
Code igniter gove the answer to the client
```

Or the reverse, which would be to host any codeigniter URL in node.js, and redirect them to whatever port codeigniter will listen.

Or you will need to configure Apache to redirect the request to port whatever codeigniter on or 8010 depending of the url.